# How to get same request headers for PHP and NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

I'm working on application in PHP + NodeJS (communication between them is by REDIS pub/sub). Most code is written in PHP, NodeJS is run in background for some tasks.
I don't know if it's good idea to use PHP+NodeJS for such things, but I want something like this:

User opens a website, in this moment Node.js is checking if user is logged. If so it grabs something from database(REDIS), let's call it 'patterns' and store it in temporary hash/list.
Then other user post something which looks like question. This question is send to NodeJS by pub/sub and Node is checking if that question match any of the active patterns (patterns from temporary hash/list).

Here is a problem that I can't figure out

**I can't get PHPSESSID in NodeJS**

I have tried:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3001);
var io = socket.listen( server );

// #1
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('New user!');
   // Here I want to check if user is logged by checking PHPSESSID
   console.log(socket.request.headers.cookie); // <-- this one doesn't return PHPSESSID (It's return only io cookie)
});

// #2
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    var cookie = handshakeData.headers.cookie;
    console.log(cookie); // <--- doens't return PHPSESSID (It's return only io cookie)

    callback(null, true);
});

// #3
var options = {method: 'GET', host: 'my-app.com', port: 80, path: '/'};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        // PHPSESSID is different then PHPSESSID in browser
    }
);
req.end();
```

Is there any way I could get current request header which contains PHPSESSID? Or is there a way to run PHP and Node in parallel? So I could get same HTTP request in PHP and NodeJS? (I use Nginx)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Redis, you can as well use it to share the session information between PHP and Node.js parts of your application. You will need to use for example `cookie` module in Node.js to retrieve the PHP session information.

More detailed answer with code samples are given here:

https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/php-and-node-js-session-share-redi/

Comment: I saw that post before. It doesn't work in my example bcuz app.get('/', function()) doesn't work for me